# Debug lambda Golang VSCode

Tags: docker, amazon-aws, golang

Estou usando o Golang com o SAM para criar funções lambdas e gostaria de saber como fazer o debug utilizando o VSCode.
Este é o comando para executar minha aplicação, que sobe na porta 3000:

```
sam local start-api --docker-network my-network
```

Comment: Acredito que, só com a extensao da aws para o vscode, voce ja. libera uma nova opcao de laucher gerado automaticamente.
Esse launcher vai ter varias variaveis, ai vc configura como quiser. Feito isso, é só dar um play

Answer (score -1):

Grande Flávio, existem tutoriais na internet de como fazer esse processo.

Você precisa utilizar a opção -d no seu comando sam e utilizar o plugin Delve(DLV) pra conseguir pegar as saídas do debug.

[na documentação fala da adição do comando -d](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/08/aws-sam-cli-supports-debugging-go-functions-and-testing-for-additional-events/)

[Issues no github Github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/1740)

[O Delve (DLV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058823/how-to-use-delve-debugger-in-visual-studio-code)

[Veja a opção -d na documentação do SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-invoke.html)